# Disable Domain Name Highlighting in Firefox 77

Tags: firefox, address-bar, firefox-77

In a fairly recent version of Firefox, the URL bar was changed to highlight the domain name of the website and make the rest of the URL a very difficult-to-read grey. At the time, I changed some things in about:config to remove this functionality. However, with the most recent update to Firefox, those changes no longer work, and I'm back to having a hard time reading the full URL.

What options do I have to return Firefox to behaving the way that I want?

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't do that for me on Windows 7 with FF 77.0.1. Have you tried a new profile?